# Script works in Windows 7 but not XP

Tags: vbscript, windows-xp

The script below is for extracting a zip to a different folder and overwriting the existing files. This script works great on Windows 7 machines but when I use this on XP machines, it still asks if I would like to overwrite. I need to have no human interaction with this script. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
strZipFile = "Location.zip"    'name of zip file
outFolder = "Location output folder" 'destination folder of unzipped files

Set objShell = CreateObject( "Shell.Application" )
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder)
intOptions = 4 + 16 + 1024
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptions
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787866) says:

> **Note**  In some cases, such as compressed (.zip) files, some option flags may be ignored by design.

This seems to be the case on WinXP, so you have to use different means when you want to force-replace existing files. You could, for instance, extract the files to a temporary folder and then copy them to the actual destination:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'create temporary folder with random name
Randomize
tempFolder = fso.BuildPath(fso.GetSpecialFolder(2), Fix(Rnd * 100000))
fso.CreateFolder tempFolder

strZipFile = "Location.zip"    'name of zip file
outFolder = "Location output folder" 'destination folder of unzipped files

Set objShell = CreateObject( "Shell.Application" )
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(tempFolder)
objTarget.CopyHere objSource

fso.CopyFolder tempFolder, outFolder, True
fso.DeleteFolder tempFolder, True   'delete temporary folder
```